# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine on VS2019 with Access

Tags: database, winforms, ms-access-2010

I am trying to connect a Microsoft Access Database on a WinForm (using VS2019 and Access 2010) but I got this error. I tried to download and install that package from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 but it didn't work. I still get that error. Does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: Try looking at your Project - Build and look at the "Platform target".  If it's "Any CPU", try "x86".

Comment: What is the Target Platform of our app? If you use AnyCpu you can install the 64bit version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` (note: `16`, not `12`). Also, you can install alongside the 32bit version of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider (if not already installed). MS Office usually installs the latter.

Comment: I am using the 64bit version of Windows and MS Office. Is it ok if I change from AnyCPU to x86 if I am using 64bit not 32bit?

Comment: If you are using the 64bit engine, use x64 for your platform, 32bit engine uses x86.

Comment: If you build your app with the `AnyCPU` profile, you can use both versions (you can install the 64bit of version of the `OLEDB.16` provider and the 32bit version of the `OLEDB.12` provider, or the other way around. Not both of the same bitness. But you can reference both). Make sure that `Prefer 32-bit` in the Project's Properties `Compile` pane is not selected.

Comment: I uninstalled OLEDB.12 and I installed OLEDB.16. I changed that property from AnyCPU to x64. I reinstalled OLEDB.12 and OLEDB.16. Nothing worked. What should I do?